# How to properly clone harddisk to external hardisk

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot, bios

First let my tell my needs:

I mainly work on my desktop PC. IT is Windows XP SP3. But sometimes i have to leave my home city for urgency and from there i have to work on my pc. So, i keep teamviewer on desktop and connect to my pc from outside thought laptop etc.

But few issues on that:
1. Some times my home internet connection goes down for long time. Thus i can't connect to my pc and work.
2. MY home pc keeps running as long as i am outside like for days (15+ days too) and that is really not a good idea. (power waste etc etc)

So, i thought about an idea.

I Purchased a portable HDD (USB3) 500GB (as my desktop HDD is 500GB too). Then i clone my PC HDD to usb HDD. So, far all is good.

Now when i connect usb hdd to laptop and boot from my usb hdd. XP boot screen shows and then blue screen comes up and restart. It loops here.

The blue screen shows following message:

The BIOS in this system is Not Fully ACPI Compliant

My Laptop bios is updated to latest version and i have check all features in bios there is no option for ACPI settings.

So, any help would be highly appreciated.

FYI, Laptop is HP Probook 450 G1

thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you convert your HDD to virtual machine disk and run it on y our laptop.

Comment: @Scorpion99, dear sir, thanks for the comment but how? i am not sure how to do that? do you mean create a virtual machine disk of my desktop hdd on usb hdd then use that vm on my laptop form that usb hdd?

and also running thought vm will be slow right?

Comment: Why don't you ditch the home PC and just purchase a nice, workstation quality laptop to use exclusively? Personally (opinions will differ) I'm a fan of T-series ThinkPads; they have roll-cage reinforced displays, carbon fiber cases, and are all milspec tested. I do freelance work and always travel, I currently have a T520 and no desktop PC. I take it everywhere; it's very well-built. There's also the W series (expensive, though) for higher performance.

Comment: @JasonC, sir, i can't shift to laptop and rely on that because,  as i have important, secure and confidential files. And in our country hijacking and stealing is daily/simple facts. So, i can loose my laptop any time. (may it's a blame excuse). however thanks for your comments though.

Answer (score 1):

Doing what I understand you want to do is not going to be possible, at least without a LOT of work and it's VERY UNLIKELY you're ever going to get a copy of your home computer running off a USB drive on a completely different system.

If you need your home PC available, you should consider one of the following options:

- Switch to using a laptop EXCLUSIVELY.
- Convert your home installation to a VM and run it as a VM on BOTH systems so that you can easily move a copy to your laptop and back when needed.  How exactly you would do this depends on a lot of factors and IF you can do this also depends on some things, such as what hardware you have connected to the home PC and how the hardware is connected.
- Find a DIFFERENT method of working. Leverage tools like OneDrive and other cloud services.
- Switch to Windows 8/8.1 Enterprise and use Windows2Go as that was designed to run from USB and bring a "copy" of your "home" PC with you.  (Enterprise is not generally available though - you'd have to buy a volume license which may require a minimum purchase of 5 volume licenses).

For a better answer, you'll need to clarify what you use your computers for and why you need to access the home system sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your original issue:

You have to disable the ACPI support on your computer from the BIOS, *if it's possible*. That's why you get that BSOD.

But Windows is *not meant to be portable*, so most certainly you will experience more issues (more commonly with drivers) if you manage to get past this. Your best bet is to *only copy the files you need* to your external drive and *synchronize* them when you're done. That would save you a lot of trouble dealing with VMs, that is, if you don't have that much time at your disposal; VMs are usually a good solution too, specially if you need to carry apps along with your files.

And regarding the title of the question:

I would suggest (I always do) that you make a backup from a Live USB or CD (preferably linux). The advantages of this approach are:

- No issues with permissons on files.
- The hard drive is not used by any other app when you do the copy, so you don't have to worry for open files.
- The filesystem is not in use, so you can copy your backup back and forth between your disk and your external drive transparently.
- You can do a 100% clone of the disk without having to extract your drive, or using another computer.

The most simple command to do a backup is this:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb ibs=4M obs=4M conv=sync,notrucn
```

Where `if` defines the source disk and and `of` the backup disk. You'll need to have a read [about linux drives and device block files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3158/hard-drive-device-partition-naming-convention-in-linux), if you're not used to these concepts. Alternatively, you can install the `gnome-disks` utility which is a GUI that can make the backup and restore process easier. If your Live OS doesn't come with it you can install it with these commands (most commonly, it depends on your Live OS):

```
apt-get install gnome-disks
```

or

```
yum install gnome-disks
```

I do formats and backups very often, so I can say this is one of the best ways to backup your data.

Comment: Before you do a dd based copy be sure to verify that the destination is the same size or larger than the source. "500GB" very rarely means 500 GB. In Linux, `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda` can be used. For the most part, GUI-based utilities like gnome-disks, gparted, Partition Master / Magic / Commander (on Windows) will verify first.

Comment: Also be wary of cloning to SSDs (not the OP's case, but for future readers). If you do, be sure to explicitly TRIM unused free space in the filesystem after writing the image to the SSD -- for ext filesystems, `fstrim` can be used on Linux; for NTFS tools like Samsung Magician (doesn't require a Samsung drive) can do it on Windows (Linux's NTFS drivers do not yet have TRIM support, at least as of April 2014; so no `fstrim` or `discard` option).

Answer (score 0):

Please Remember that When GHOSTING or Cloning a Computer, The Hardware on BOTH MACHINES MUST BE IDENTICAL, You can't just clone a Computer to any other computer, You will have driver and Startup issues, not to mention that your copy of windows, after each clone will keep asking you to Register your copy of windows again,  this is to prevent against piracy,  I suggest you look into how to set up a virtual Machine